# How to add a string to a .txt file in all rows excluding few characters using sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file named `xid.txt`:

```
xid: SC48028 id: artf398444
xid: indv1000 id: indv24519
xid: SC32173 id: artf398402
xid: SC21033 id: artf398372
xid: 1001 id: tracker4868
xid: wiki1000 id: wiki10709
xid: proj1234 id: proj12556
```

I need to add a string 'PT_' before 'SC48028' , 'SC32173' ... so on. The string 'SC...' can start with any combination may be 'AC...' or 'DL..'

Required output:

```
xid: PT_SC48028 id: artf398444
xid: indv1000 id: indv24519
xid: PT_SC32173 id: artf398402
xid: PT_SC21033 id: artf398372
xid: 1001 id: tracker4868
xid: wiki1000 id: wiki10709
xid: proj1234 id: proj12556
```

If you see the above output, we should not insert 'PT_' before strings which start with 'i' , 'p' , 'w' & 'numerical' . I have tried a few basic commands for my requirement using insert/append in sed.

Comment: Your question is on topic and welcome here, but you might be interested in our new [bioinformatics.se] site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With ***awk***:

```
awk '$2~/^[A-Z][A-Z]/{ $2="PT_"$2 }1' xid.txt
```

The output:

```
xid: PT_SC48028 id: artf398444
xid: indv1000 id: indv24519
xid: PT_SC32173 id: artf398402
xid: PT_SC21033 id: artf398372
xid: 1001 id: tracker4868
xid: wiki1000 id: wiki10709
xid: proj1234 id: proj12556
```

---

- `$2~/^[A-Z][A-Z]/` - if the 2nd field starts with 2 uppercase letters

---

Or ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i 's/^\(xid:[[:space:]]*\)\([A-Z]\{2\}[^[:space:]]*\)/\1PT_\2/' xid.txt
```

Comment: this was so smooth, instant answer thanks a lot. If i want to append in the existing input file what should be done ?

Comment: `awk '$2~/^[A-Z]{2}/{ $2="PT_"$2 }1' xid.txt > xid-tmp && mv xid-tmp xid.txt` or use my second approach

Comment: @SubratSahoo If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Also, @SubratSahoo (and Roman) newer versions of GNU `awk` (the one you usually have installed on Linux systems) has `-i inplace` which allows you to edit a file in place, like sed and perl's `-i`.

Comment: @terdon, yes, I know about `-i inplace` (I've suggested a unified approach  with `mv` command for the OP to fit portability). As for `Bioinformatics beta` community: I've just joined it. Could be there tasks related to Linux/Python programming/processing? How do you think?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, using `mv` is far more portable. I just wanted to mention the inplace thing as well. As for bioinformatics, yes, we do accept text parsing stuff there when the text being parsed is related to biological analyses. It's great that you joined! If you're not a bioinformatician though, there won't be much for you to answer, but there may be some. And it's a brand new, tiny beta site at the moment so there's not much anyway.

Comment: Why do you use extended mode (`-r`) with `sed`? It makes reading and writing scripts much easier.

Comment: @someonewithpc, `-E` is more portable than `-r`. Use `-r` in your scripts

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest How is `-E` more portable? It's not even present on my version of `sed` (GNU 4.2.2). Are you sure you're not confusing it with `grep`?

Comment: @someonewithpc, you are wrong. I also have `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. Look into documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE. `sed -E` is also should work on OSX

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just in case, if i need to print the same stuff but if i do not want to print PT before "indv1000" , "proj" , "indn" ,"wiki" . What are the options can i use ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have tried awk '$2~/^[A-Z]|^[a-z]/{ $2="PT_"$2 }1 $2 !~ /indv/'
but it would remove the line

Answer (score 6):

sed option

```
sed -i -e 's/[A-Z][A-Z]/PT_&/' file
```

where

- `-i` edit in place
- `-e` command to execute